Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 USB Cameras detected but cheese nor snapshot show as detected
I spent time reading just about every post I could find about this topic.  The device is an Intel NUC mini PC with a Logitech C920 and a Brio 510 plugged into it to see if I could get either to work.  I have had the connected to the system individually and together with the same results.
I have done lsusb and it shows both devices.  I have done v4l2-ctl --list-devices and both cameras have shown up there.  I have tried using snapshot, cheese, and guvcview to no avail.  None of them detect any available cameras.  I have tailed the logs while trying to launch the different apps and plug/unplug the devices and nothing of value.
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
HD Pro Webcam C920 (usb-0000:00:14.0-4):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media0

Brio 505 (usb-0000:39:00.0-1):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:08e5 Logitech, Inc. C920 PRO HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0919 Logitech, Inc. Brio 505
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

I am looking for some suggestions to move forward.  Like I had stated, I thought maybe it was an issue with server vs desktop and have had both installed with the same ending results.  I have tested these cameras without issue with Windows and Mac.

Please try LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /path/to/cheese  The correct path to cheese you can find with which cheese
